# Interface/enum listing standard mime-type constants

Tags: java, gwt, mime-types, content-type, guava

I am looking among the standard libraries (like apache commons, jax, jboss, javax) for an interface or enum that lists the values of all the standard mime-type (aka content-type).

This interface should not be encumbered with too deep with other classes that would make it difficult to include the whole bunch as gwt source code.

for example

```
interface ContentType{
  String JSON = "Application/JSON";
  blah ... blah ...
}
```

or,

```
enum ContentType{
  JSON("Application/JSON"),
  blah ... blah ...
}
```

Comment: I suppose you've already seen Apache Sling? http://sling.apache.org/site/mime-type-support-commonsmime.html

Answer (score 76, accepted):

## *Guava* library

We have a [*Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) class for this: [`com.google.common.net.MediaType`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html).

It was released with Guava 12 as stated in the source code and in [Issue 823](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=823#c9). [Sources](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/net/MediaType.java) are available, too.

Comment: If you are looking for mime type mappings with extensions (like I was), check [MimeTypes](https://github.com/amr/mimetypes) which I wrote few hours ago out of need.

Comment: It's a pity there are no String constants defined in `com.google.common.net.MediaType`, as `MediaType.toString()`isn't a compile time constant and therefore not usable in annotations

Comment: This is actually an enumeration of MIME media types. The other solutions are not.

Answer (score 118):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html :

```
staticjava.lang.String APPLICATION_ATOM_XML             "application/atom+xml"
staticMediaType        APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_TYPE        "application/atom+xml"
staticjava.lang.String APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED      "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
staticMediaType        APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
staticjava.lang.String APPLICATION_JSON                 "application/json"
staticMediaType        APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE            "application/json"
staticjava.lang.String APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM         "application/octet-stream"
staticMediaType        APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE    "application/octet-stream"
staticjava.lang.String APPLICATION_SVG_XML              "application/svg+xml"
staticMediaType        APPLICATION_SVG_XML_TYPE         "application/svg+xml"
staticjava.lang.String APPLICATION_XHTML_XML            "application/xhtml+xml"
staticMediaType        APPLICATION_XHTML_XML_TYPE       "application/xhtml+xml"
staticjava.lang.String APPLICATION_XML                  "application/xml"
staticMediaType        APPLICATION_XML_TYPE             "application/xml"
staticjava.lang.String MEDIA_TYPE_WILDCARD              The value of a type or subtype wildcard: "*"
staticjava.lang.String MULTIPART_FORM_DATA              "multipart/form-data"
staticMediaType        MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE         "multipart/form-data"
staticjava.lang.String TEXT_HTML                        "text/html"
staticMediaType        TEXT_HTML_TYPE                   "text/html"
staticjava.lang.String TEXT_PLAIN                       "text/plain"
staticMediaType        TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE                  "text/plain"
staticjava.lang.String TEXT_XML                         "text/xml"
staticMediaType        TEXT_XML_TYPE                    "text/xml"
staticjava.lang.String WILDCARD                         "*/*"
staticMediaType        WILDCARD_TYPE                    "*/*"
```

Answer (score 101):

If you are using [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/) then there is a [MediaType](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) class for common content types:

```
MediaType.TEXT_HTML 
MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN 
MediaType.TEXT_XML 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON 
MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG 
...
```

Comment: This worked well for me but I needed to use the MediaType.foo_VALUE portion. Each class has a corresponding _VALUE that's the String.

Comment: I did request, the innterface/eunum should not be encumbered too deep with other classes, that would make it impossible to be used in GWT. GWT requires source code not byte code, because GWTis a transpiler from Java to JavaScript. Spring framework is not usable on the browser side of GWT.

Comment: This is working good until you need a constant for "application/zip". This class doesn't have `APPLICATION_ZIP`

Answer (score 21):

There is now also the class [`org.apache.http.entity.ContentType`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html) from package `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore`, starting from 4.2 up.

Comment: Thanks, but the javadoc for that class says it was added in v4.2. I can vouch that it's not in v4.0.1, which is what I'm stuck with for now.

Comment: I used this until I needed `application/pdf` mime type. Unfortunately, this class does not have a constant for pdf :(

Answer (score 17):

`javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` from [JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html)

Answer (score 5):

Java 7 to the rescue!

You can either pass the file or the file name and it will return the MIME type.

```
String mimeType = MimetypesFileTypeMap
    .getDefaultFileTypeMap()
    .getContentType(attachment.getFileName());
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html

Comment: This doesn't enumerate the MIME types that exist, though.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a `MediaType` class in [androidannotations](http://androidannotations.org/) in case you want to use with android! See [here](http://javadox.com/org.androidannotations/androidannotations-api/3.2/org/androidannotations/api/rest/MediaType.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you're on android you have multiple choices, where only the first is a kind of "enum":

- [`HTTP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HTTP.html) (which has been deprecated in API 22), for example
  `HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE` or
- [`MimeTypeMap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html), for example
  `final String mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);`
  See also [`FileProvider.getType()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/39b32a9feea6b821d6a5c92202c400aa1f252200/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java#L449).
- [`URLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) that provides the following methods:

  - [`guessContentTypeFromStream(InputStream is)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)
  - [`guessContentTypeFromName(String url)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName%28java.lang.String%29)
  - [`getFileNameMap()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getFileNameMap%28%29)

For example

```
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return URLConnection.getFileNameMap().getContentTypeFor(
            uri.getLastPathSegment());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by an answer above, you can use `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` which has the required constants.

I also wanted to share a really cool and handy link which I found that gives a reference to all the Javax constants in one place - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a static class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MimeTypes {

    private static final HashMap<String, String> mimeTypes;

    static {
        mimeTypes = new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put(".323", "text/h323");
                put(".3g2", "video/3gpp2");
                put(".3gp", "video/3gpp");
                put(".3gp2", "video/3gpp2");
                put(".3gpp", "video/3gpp");
                put(".7z", "application/x-7z-compressed");
                put(".aa", "audio/audible");
                put(".AAC", "audio/aac");
                put(".aaf", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".aax", "audio/vnd.audible.aax");
                put(".ac3", "audio/ac3");
                put(".aca", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".accda", "application/msaccess.addin");
                put(".accdb", "application/msaccess");
                put(".accdc", "application/msaccess.cab");
                put(".accde", "application/msaccess");
                put(".accdr", "application/msaccess.runtime");
                put(".accdt", "application/msaccess");
                put(".accdw", "application/msaccess.webapplication");
                put(".accft", "application/msaccess.ftemplate");
                put(".acx", "application/internet-property-stream");
                put(".AddIn", "text/xml");
                put(".ade", "application/msaccess");
                put(".adobebridge", "application/x-bridge-url");
                put(".adp", "application/msaccess");
                put(".ADT", "audio/vnd.dlna.adts");
                put(".ADTS", "audio/aac");
                put(".afm", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".ai", "application/postscript");
                put(".aif", "audio/x-aiff");
                put(".aifc", "audio/aiff");
                put(".aiff", "audio/aiff");
                put(".air", "application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip");
                put(".amc", "application/x-mpeg");
                put(".application", "application/x-ms-application");
                put(".art", "image/x-jg");
                put(".asa", "application/xml");
                put(".asax", "application/xml");
                put(".ascx", "application/xml");
                put(".asd", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".asf", "video/x-ms-asf");
                put(".ashx", "application/xml");
                put(".asi", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".asm", "text/plain");
                put(".asmx", "application/xml");
                put(".aspx", "application/xml");
                put(".asr", "video/x-ms-asf");
                put(".asx", "video/x-ms-asf");
                put(".atom", "application/atom+xml");
                put(".au", "audio/basic");
                put(".avi", "video/x-msvideo");
                put(".axs", "application/olescript");
                put(".bas", "text/plain");
                put(".bcpio", "application/x-bcpio");
                put(".bin", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".bmp", "image/bmp");
                put(".c", "text/plain");
                put(".cab", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".caf", "audio/x-caf");
                put(".calx", "application/vnd.ms-office.calx");
                put(".cat", "application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat");
                put(".cc", "text/plain");
                put(".cd", "text/plain");
                put(".cdda", "audio/aiff");
                put(".cdf", "application/x-cdf");
                put(".cer", "application/x-x509-ca-cert");
                put(".chm", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".class", "application/x-java-applet");
                put(".clp", "application/x-msclip");
                put(".cmx", "image/x-cmx");
                put(".cnf", "text/plain");
                put(".cod", "image/cis-cod");
                put(".config", "application/xml");
                put(".contact", "text/x-ms-contact");
                put(".coverage", "application/xml");
                put(".cpio", "application/x-cpio");
                put(".cpp", "text/plain");
                put(".crd", "application/x-mscardfile");
                put(".crl", "application/pkix-crl");
                put(".crt", "application/x-x509-ca-cert");
                put(".cs", "text/plain");
                put(".csdproj", "text/plain");
                put(".csh", "application/x-csh");
                put(".csproj", "text/plain");
                put(".css", "text/css");
                put(".csv", "text/csv");
                put(".cur", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".cxx", "text/plain");
                put(".dat", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".datasource", "application/xml");
                put(".dbproj", "text/plain");
                put(".dcr", "application/x-director");
                put(".def", "text/plain");
                put(".deploy", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".der", "application/x-x509-ca-cert");
                put(".dgml", "application/xml");
                put(".dib", "image/bmp");
                put(".dif", "video/x-dv");
                put(".dir", "application/x-director");
                put(".disco", "text/xml");
                put(".dll", "application/x-msdownload");
                put(".dll.config", "text/xml");
                put(".dlm", "text/dlm");
                put(".doc", "application/msword");
                put(".docm", "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
                put(".dot", "application/msword");
                put(".dotm", "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".dotx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template");
                put(".dsp", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".dsw", "text/plain");
                put(".dtd", "text/xml");
                put(".dtsConfig", "text/xml");
                put(".dv", "video/x-dv");
                put(".dvi", "application/x-dvi");
                put(".dwf", "drawing/x-dwf");
                put(".dwp", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".dxr", "application/x-director");
                put(".eml", "message/rfc822");
                put(".emz", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".eot", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".eps", "application/postscript");
                put(".etl", "application/etl");
                put(".etx", "text/x-setext");
                put(".evy", "application/envoy");
                put(".exe", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".exe.config", "text/xml");
                put(".fdf", "application/vnd.fdf");
                put(".fif", "application/fractals");
                put(".filters", "Application/xml");
                put(".fla", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".flr", "x-world/x-vrml");
                put(".flv", "video/x-flv");
                put(".fsscript", "application/fsharp-script");
                put(".fsx", "application/fsharp-script");
                put(".generictest", "application/xml");
                put(".gif", "image/gif");
                put(".group", "text/x-ms-group");
                put(".gsm", "audio/x-gsm");
                put(".gtar", "application/x-gtar");
                put(".gz", "application/x-gzip");
                put(".h", "text/plain");
                put(".hdf", "application/x-hdf");
                put(".hdml", "text/x-hdml");
                put(".hhc", "application/x-oleobject");
                put(".hhk", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hhp", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hlp", "application/winhlp");
                put(".hpp", "text/plain");
                put(".hqx", "application/mac-binhex40");
                put(".hta", "application/hta");
                put(".htc", "text/x-component");
                put(".htm", "text/html");
                put(".html", "text/html");
                put(".htt", "text/webviewhtml");
                put(".hxa", "application/xml");
                put(".hxc", "application/xml");
                put(".hxd", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hxe", "application/xml");
                put(".hxf", "application/xml");
                put(".hxh", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hxi", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hxk", "application/xml");
                put(".hxq", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hxr", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hxs", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hxt", "text/html");
                put(".hxv", "application/xml");
                put(".hxw", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".hxx", "text/plain");
                put(".i", "text/plain");
                put(".ico", "image/x-icon");
                put(".ics", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".idl", "text/plain");
                put(".ief", "image/ief");
                put(".iii", "application/x-iphone");
                put(".inc", "text/plain");
                put(".inf", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".inl", "text/plain");
                put(".ins", "application/x-internet-signup");
                put(".ipa", "application/x-itunes-ipa");
                put(".ipg", "application/x-itunes-ipg");
                put(".ipproj", "text/plain");
                put(".ipsw", "application/x-itunes-ipsw");
                put(".iqy", "text/x-ms-iqy");
                put(".isp", "application/x-internet-signup");
                put(".ite", "application/x-itunes-ite");
                put(".itlp", "application/x-itunes-itlp");
                put(".itms", "application/x-itunes-itms");
                put(".itpc", "application/x-itunes-itpc");
                put(".IVF", "video/x-ivf");
                put(".jar", "application/java-archive");
                put(".java", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".jck", "application/liquidmotion");
                put(".jcz", "application/liquidmotion");
                put(".jfif", "image/pjpeg");
                put(".jnlp", "application/x-java-jnlp-file");
                put(".jpb", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".jpe", "image/jpeg");
                put(".jpeg", "image/jpeg");
                put(".jpg", "image/jpeg");
                put(".js", "application/x-javascript");
                put(".json", "application/json");
                put(".jsx", "text/jscript");
                put(".jsxbin", "text/plain");
                put(".latex", "application/x-latex");
                put(".library-ms", "application/windows-library+xml");
                put(".lit", "application/x-ms-reader");
                put(".loadtest", "application/xml");
                put(".lpk", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".lsf", "video/x-la-asf");
                put(".lst", "text/plain");
                put(".lsx", "video/x-la-asf");
                put(".lzh", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".m13", "application/x-msmediaview");
                put(".m14", "application/x-msmediaview");
                put(".m1v", "video/mpeg");
                put(".m2t", "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts");
                put(".m2ts", "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts");
                put(".m2v", "video/mpeg");
                put(".m3u", "audio/x-mpegurl");
                put(".m3u8", "audio/x-mpegurl");
                put(".m4a", "audio/m4a");
                put(".m4b", "audio/m4b");
                put(".m4p", "audio/m4p");
                put(".m4r", "audio/x-m4r");
                put(".m4v", "video/x-m4v");
                put(".mac", "image/x-macpaint");
                put(".mak", "text/plain");
                put(".man", "application/x-troff-man");
                put(".manifest", "application/x-ms-manifest");
                put(".map", "text/plain");
                put(".master", "application/xml");
                put(".mda", "application/msaccess");
                put(".mdb", "application/x-msaccess");
                put(".mde", "application/msaccess");
                put(".mdp", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".me", "application/x-troff-me");
                put(".mfp", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
                put(".mht", "message/rfc822");
                put(".mhtml", "message/rfc822");
                put(".mid", "audio/mid");
                put(".midi", "audio/mid");
                put(".mix", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".mk", "text/plain");
                put(".mmf", "application/x-smaf");
                put(".mno", "text/xml");
                put(".mny", "application/x-msmoney");
                put(".mod", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mov", "video/quicktime");
                put(".movie", "video/x-sgi-movie");
                put(".mp2", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mp2v", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mp3", "audio/mpeg");
                put(".mp4", "video/mp4");
                put(".mp4v", "video/mp4");
                put(".mpa", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mpe", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mpeg", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mpf", "application/vnd.ms-mediapackage");
                put(".mpg", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mpp", "application/vnd.ms-project");
                put(".mpv2", "video/mpeg");
                put(".mqv", "video/quicktime");
                put(".ms", "application/x-troff-ms");
                put(".msi", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".mso", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".mts", "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts");
                put(".mtx", "application/xml");
                put(".mvb", "application/x-msmediaview");
                put(".mvc", "application/x-miva-compiled");
                put(".mxp", "application/x-mmxp");
                put(".nc", "application/x-netcdf");
                put(".nsc", "video/x-ms-asf");
                put(".nws", "message/rfc822");
                put(".ocx", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".oda", "application/oda");
                put(".odc", "text/x-ms-odc");
                put(".odh", "text/plain");
                put(".odl", "text/plain");
                put(".odp", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation");
                put(".ods", "application/oleobject");
                put(".odt", "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text");
                put(".one", "application/onenote");
                put(".onea", "application/onenote");
                put(".onepkg", "application/onenote");
                put(".onetmp", "application/onenote");
                put(".onetoc", "application/onenote");
                put(".onetoc2", "application/onenote");
                put(".orderedtest", "application/xml");
                put(".osdx", "application/opensearchdescription+xml");
                put(".p10", "application/pkcs10");
                put(".p12", "application/x-pkcs12");
                put(".p7b", "application/x-pkcs7-certificates");
                put(".p7c", "application/pkcs7-mime");
                put(".p7m", "application/pkcs7-mime");
                put(".p7r", "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp");
                put(".p7s", "application/pkcs7-signature");
                put(".pbm", "image/x-portable-bitmap");
                put(".pcast", "application/x-podcast");
                put(".pct", "image/pict");
                put(".pcx", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".pcz", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".pdf", "application/pdf");
                put(".pfb", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".pfm", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".pfx", "application/x-pkcs12");
                put(".pgm", "image/x-portable-graymap");
                put(".pic", "image/pict");
                put(".pict", "image/pict");
                put(".pkgdef", "text/plain");
                put(".pkgundef", "text/plain");
                put(".pko", "application/vnd.ms-pki.pko");
                put(".pls", "audio/scpls");
                put(".pma", "application/x-perfmon");
                put(".pmc", "application/x-perfmon");
                put(".pml", "application/x-perfmon");
                put(".pmr", "application/x-perfmon");
                put(".pmw", "application/x-perfmon");
                put(".png", "image/png");
                put(".pnm", "image/x-portable-anymap");
                put(".pnt", "image/x-macpaint");
                put(".pntg", "image/x-macpaint");
                put(".pnz", "image/png");
                put(".pot", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
                put(".potm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".potx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template");
                put(".ppa", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
                put(".ppam", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".ppm", "image/x-portable-pixmap");
                put(".pps", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
                put(".ppsm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".ppsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow");
                put(".ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
                put(".pptm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".pptx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation");
                put(".prf", "application/pics-rules");
                put(".prm", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".prx", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".ps", "application/postscript");
                put(".psc1", "application/PowerShell");
                put(".psd", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".psess", "application/xml");
                put(".psm", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".psp", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".pub", "application/x-mspublisher");
                put(".pwz", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
                put(".qht", "text/x-html-insertion");
                put(".qhtm", "text/x-html-insertion");
                put(".qt", "video/quicktime");
                put(".qti", "image/x-quicktime");
                put(".qtif", "image/x-quicktime");
                put(".qtl", "application/x-quicktimeplayer");
                put(".qxd", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".ra", "audio/x-pn-realaudio");
                put(".ram", "audio/x-pn-realaudio");
                put(".rar", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".ras", "image/x-cmu-raster");
                put(".rat", "application/rat-file");
                put(".rc", "text/plain");
                put(".rc2", "text/plain");
                put(".rct", "text/plain");
                put(".rdlc", "application/xml");
                put(".resx", "application/xml");
                put(".rf", "image/vnd.rn-realflash");
                put(".rgb", "image/x-rgb");
                put(".rgs", "text/plain");
                put(".rm", "application/vnd.rn-realmedia");
                put(".rmi", "audio/mid");
                put(".rmp", "application/vnd.rn-rn_music_package");
                put(".roff", "application/x-troff");
                put(".rpm", "audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin");
                put(".rqy", "text/x-ms-rqy");
                put(".rtf", "application/rtf");
                put(".rtx", "text/richtext");
                put(".ruleset", "application/xml");
                put(".s", "text/plain");
                put(".safariextz", "application/x-safari-safariextz");
                put(".scd", "application/x-msschedule");
                put(".sct", "text/scriptlet");
                put(".sd2", "audio/x-sd2");
                put(".sdp", "application/sdp");
                put(".sea", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".searchConnector-ms", "application/windows-search-connector+xml");
                put(".setpay", "application/set-payment-initiation");
                put(".setreg", "application/set-registration-initiation");
                put(".settings", "application/xml");
                put(".sgimb", "application/x-sgimb");
                put(".sgml", "text/sgml");
                put(".sh", "application/x-sh");
                put(".shar", "application/x-shar");
                put(".shtml", "text/html");
                put(".sit", "application/x-stuffit");
                put(".sitemap", "application/xml");
                put(".skin", "application/xml");
                put(".sldm", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".sldx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide");
                put(".slk", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".sln", "text/plain");
                put(".slupkg-ms", "application/x-ms-license");
                put(".smd", "audio/x-smd");
                put(".smi", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".smx", "audio/x-smd");
                put(".smz", "audio/x-smd");
                put(".snd", "audio/basic");
                put(".snippet", "application/xml");
                put(".snp", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".sol", "text/plain");
                put(".sor", "text/plain");
                put(".spc", "application/x-pkcs7-certificates");
                put(".spl", "application/futuresplash");
                put(".src", "application/x-wais-source");
                put(".srf", "text/plain");
                put(".SSISDeploymentManifest", "text/xml");
                put(".ssm", "application/streamingmedia");
                put(".sst", "application/vnd.ms-pki.certstore");
                put(".stl", "application/vnd.ms-pki.stl");
                put(".sv4cpio", "application/x-sv4cpio");
                put(".sv4crc", "application/x-sv4crc");
                put(".svc", "application/xml");
                put(".swf", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
                put(".t", "application/x-troff");
                put(".tar", "application/x-tar");
                put(".tcl", "application/x-tcl");
                put(".testrunconfig", "application/xml");
                put(".testsettings", "application/xml");
                put(".tex", "application/x-tex");
                put(".texi", "application/x-texinfo");
                put(".texinfo", "application/x-texinfo");
                put(".tgz", "application/x-compressed");
                put(".thmx", "application/vnd.ms-officetheme");
                put(".thn", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".tif", "image/tiff");
                put(".tiff", "image/tiff");
                put(".tlh", "text/plain");
                put(".tli", "text/plain");
                put(".toc", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".tr", "application/x-troff");
                put(".trm", "application/x-msterminal");
                put(".trx", "application/xml");
                put(".ts", "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts");
                put(".tsv", "text/tab-separated-values");
                put(".ttf", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".tts", "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts");
                put(".txt", "text/plain");
                put(".u32", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".uls", "text/iuls");
                put(".user", "text/plain");
                put(".ustar", "application/x-ustar");
                put(".vb", "text/plain");
                put(".vbdproj", "text/plain");
                put(".vbk", "video/mpeg");
                put(".vbproj", "text/plain");
                put(".vbs", "text/vbscript");
                put(".vcf", "text/x-vcard");
                put(".vcproj", "Application/xml");
                put(".vcs", "text/plain");
                put(".vcxproj", "Application/xml");
                put(".vddproj", "text/plain");
                put(".vdp", "text/plain");
                put(".vdproj", "text/plain");
                put(".vdx", "application/vnd.ms-visio.viewer");
                put(".vml", "text/xml");
                put(".vscontent", "application/xml");
                put(".vsct", "text/xml");
                put(".vsd", "application/vnd.visio");
                put(".vsi", "application/ms-vsi");
                put(".vsix", "application/vsix");
                put(".vsixlangpack", "text/xml");
                put(".vsixmanifest", "text/xml");
                put(".vsmdi", "application/xml");
                put(".vspscc", "text/plain");
                put(".vss", "application/vnd.visio");
                put(".vsscc", "text/plain");
                put(".vssettings", "text/xml");
                put(".vssscc", "text/plain");
                put(".vst", "application/vnd.visio");
                put(".vstemplate", "text/xml");
                put(".vsto", "application/x-ms-vsto");
                put(".vsw", "application/vnd.visio");
                put(".vsx", "application/vnd.visio");
                put(".vtx", "application/vnd.visio");
                put(".wav", "audio/wav");
                put(".wave", "audio/wav");
                put(".wax", "audio/x-ms-wax");
                put(".wbk", "application/msword");
                put(".wbmp", "image/vnd.wap.wbmp");
                put(".wcm", "application/vnd.ms-works");
                put(".wdb", "application/vnd.ms-works");
                put(".wdp", "image/vnd.ms-photo");
                put(".webarchive", "application/x-safari-webarchive");
                put(".webtest", "application/xml");
                put(".wiq", "application/xml");
                put(".wiz", "application/msword");
                put(".wks", "application/vnd.ms-works");
                put(".WLMP", "application/wlmoviemaker");
                put(".wlpginstall", "application/x-wlpg-detect");
                put(".wlpginstall3", "application/x-wlpg3-detect");
                put(".wm", "video/x-ms-wm");
                put(".wma", "audio/x-ms-wma");
                put(".wmd", "application/x-ms-wmd");
                put(".wmf", "application/x-msmetafile");
                put(".wml", "text/vnd.wap.wml");
                put(".wmlc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlc");
                put(".wmls", "text/vnd.wap.wmlscript");
                put(".wmlsc", "application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc");
                put(".wmp", "video/x-ms-wmp");
                put(".wmv", "video/x-ms-wmv");
                put(".wmx", "video/x-ms-wmx");
                put(".wmz", "application/x-ms-wmz");
                put(".wpl", "application/vnd.ms-wpl");
                put(".wps", "application/vnd.ms-works");
                put(".wri", "application/x-mswrite");
                put(".wrl", "x-world/x-vrml");
                put(".wrz", "x-world/x-vrml");
                put(".wsc", "text/scriptlet");
                put(".wsdl", "text/xml");
                put(".wvx", "video/x-ms-wvx");
                put(".x", "application/directx");
                put(".xaf", "x-world/x-vrml");
                put(".xaml", "application/xaml+xml");
                put(".xap", "application/x-silverlight-app");
                put(".xbap", "application/x-ms-xbap");
                put(".xbm", "image/x-xbitmap");
                put(".xdr", "text/plain");
                put(".xht", "application/xhtml+xml");
                put(".xhtml", "application/xhtml+xml");
                put(".xla", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xlam", "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".xlc", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xld", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xlk", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xll", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xlm", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xlsb", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".xlsm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                put(".xlt", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xltm", "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12");
                put(".xltx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template");
                put(".xlw", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                put(".xml", "text/xml");
                put(".xmta", "application/xml");
                put(".xof", "x-world/x-vrml");
                put(".XOML", "text/plain");
                put(".xpm", "image/x-xpixmap");
                put(".xps", "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument");
                put(".xrm-ms", "text/xml");
                put(".xsc", "application/xml");
                put(".xsd", "text/xml");
                put(".xsf", "text/xml");
                put(".xsl", "text/xml");
                put(".xslt", "text/xml");
                put(".xsn", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".xss", "application/xml");
                put(".xtp", "application/octet-stream");
                put(".xwd", "image/x-xwindowdump");
                put(".z", "application/x-compress");
                put(".zip", "application/x-zip-compressed");
            }
        };
    }

    public static String getMimeType(String extension) {
        if (extension == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!extension.startsWith(".")) {
            extension = "." + extension.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        }

        String mime = mimeTypes.get(extension);

        return mime != null ? mime : "application/octet-stream";
    }
}
```

Comment: I love this solution :), What is that: "think twice code once", sorry I'm busy coding.

Comment: Agreed: don't take a new dependency. In fairness to the OP, they're looking for something they might already have imported... but I like this answer better.

Answer (score -4):

As already posted in earlier answer, most common MIME types are configured in a webserver. For example in tomcat conf/ we have web.xml with following MIME configured:

```
   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>abs</extension>
      <mime-type>audio/x-mpeg</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>ai</extension>
      <mime-type>application/postscript</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
      <extension>aif</extension>
      <mime-type>audio/x-aiff</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
...
```

Create a startup listener that kicks in when web app is started and parses this XML file and creates the ENUMS for you and binds it to servlet context for sharing downstream.

Comment: This sounds utterly complex for a simple requirement as having a list of available mimetypes.
Furthermore, mimetypes won't change much, so why would you parse them over and over again? That is what enums and constants are for.

Comment: Why reinvent wheel when the list is already in the web server. Why hardcode something- just write a simple xml parser to read the values and cache it once when web server starts. Tomorrow, if you need to support a new MIME type, your webserver needs to be updated anyway and restarted, A parser approach helps in those situations. Instead of changing at multple places, just change the web server config.

Comment: If you want to support a new mime type, you will most likely write some custom code anyway as there is no way of generically handle a new mimetype. (Except you just pass it through to another system, in which case you don't need to parse it anyway.)