# Is there an enum with MIME Types in Java?

Tags: java, mime, apache-commons, guava

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface/enum listing standard mime-type constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854909/interface-enum-listing-standard-mime-type-constants)

Is there an enum (or something similar) which holds constants for the most common MIME types?

I'd like to deal with some constants rather than firing Strings here and there.

Comment: An issue is that mimetypes are open-ended.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for pointing this out. Adjusted my question.

Comment: I presume you've covered this already, but classes often provide a closed list of the mime types they support. ImageIO is an example of this. Unless you are writing something at the framework level, you may find you can get an appropriate list of mime types from the class you're trying to interact with. I mention this just in case what you really need is a relevant subset of mime types appropriate to your situation.

Comment: You can use org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is not one in the JDK that I am aware of. But there is [this class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/enumMimeType.htm) that you can probably start with.

Edit:

Now there is a better option I think. Using Guava's [MediaType](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html) is a class that is maintained.

Comment: Not really in JDK but Java EE:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html

Answer (score 8):

There cannot be an enum, since there is no closed set of possible values.

Several frameworks provide convenient classes that contain list of Strings. For example JAX-RS (jsr311) spec provides a class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.

Comment: MediaType is not an enum but its also another good option.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html

Answer (score 0):

Java stores some MIME types in [DataFlavor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html).