# Are there constants for the Request types in Java

Tags: java

I am using the [java.net.HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod%28java.lang.String%29) object to set the request method. I am about to construct an enum to handle the possible values but it seems silly this isn't already done. Am I missing something? Is there an Enum somewhere with all of these values?

**Update**

The Content Type can be handled with a JAX-RS class see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854909/interface-enum-listing-standard-mime-type-constants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `java.net` package does not have such constants. You can instead use an Http Client library like Apache's [Http Components](http://hc.apache.org/) which does provide such functionality, but not necessarily in the form of enums.

Answer (score 1):

For media type constants, take a look at the constants at Spring 3 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html

For request methods constants, look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html

Comment: Using websphere so I would rather avoid screwing around with the classpath to get Spring to work well.

Comment: You can use this jar with WAS without any trouble.

Comment: Ok I will look into it but again I think it would be better to use the JAX-RS classes. This also still doesn't help me with GET, PUT, DELETE, PUT which is what the question is about. I edited to remove MediaType since that was a duplicate.